# The purpose of $page in node.tpl.php and when does it become FALSE?

Tags: nodes, theming, 7

I noticed that there is a variable `$page` in [node.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/11816) and it is usually `TRUE`.
The node title is not displayed while it is `TRUE`, but in **page.tpl.php**, the node title has been displayed as a page title. The below is the code snippet from node.tpl.php of Bartik theme.

```
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

When the variable is `FALSE`, the node title in **node.tpl.php** will be displayed and it seems like duplicate title being displayed. I tried this:

```
function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-full';
  }
  dpm($variables);
  $variables['page'] = FALSE;
}
```

What is the purpose of this variable and when does it become `FALSE`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$page` is TRUE if the node is being shown in its own full page.

If the path is "node/34", `$page` is TRUE.
If the path is "taxonomy/term/5", `$page` is FALSE.

If the node is tagged to taxonomy term 5, it will also be displayed in node listing page at "taxonomy/term/5" in teaser by default. So you do need to add the title and attributes with a link to the node.

But in the full page, title is printed at the **page.tpl.php** level so you don't need to print it again.

The variable `$teaser` is **usually** the inverse of `$page` but you can pass `$teaser` and `$page` both FALSE by making a View on content (not fields) to show full node.

Use `$page` to determine the path of the node. If it's already the node path, you don't have to make a link to node.

Comment: @Sithu thanks for the edits. I'm in a train with a mobile right now so formatting is just like Lil Wayne's face or songs.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm in the office. Edits can be done easily :)

Comment: I'm not clear on your last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

That variable becomes false in:

[template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

with

```
$variables['page'] = $variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($node);
```

See also:

[node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7)

For the view_mode parameter used there.

The output of the node `$title` is controlled by `page.tpl.php` for the full page node view.

Comment: Thanks, David. It sounds like you only answered the second part of the question.

Comment: The output of the node `$title` is controlled by `page.tpl.php` for the full page node view.